# Latitude/Longitude not woking in EXIFR gem for Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems, latitude-longitude, exif

Am trying to use the exifr gem to read lat/long for an image upload.

In the model:

```
attr_accessible :image, :post_process_photo, :width, :height, :model, :datetime, :latitude, :longitude

belongs_to :user

  has_attached_file :image, styles: { medium: "300x300#", thumb: "50x50#", large:"500x500#" }

  after_post_process  :post_process_photo 

    def post_process_photo
      imgfile = EXIFR::JPEG.new(image.queued_for_write[:original].path)
      return unless imgfile

      self.width         = imgfile.width             
      self.height        = imgfile.height            
      self.model         = imgfile.model             
      self.datetime      = imgfile.date_time    
      self.latitude      = imgfile.gps.latitude  
      self.longitude     = imgfile.gps.longitude  

       end
```

In the view... the width/height stuff is working, but lat/long isn't:

```
<%= @pic.width  %>  #this works!

<%= @pic.height  %> #this works!

<%= @pic.latitude  %> #this doesn't!

<%= @pic.longitude  %> #this doesn't!
```

...which is odd, because it's marked up exactly as instructed in the [gem docs](https://github.com/remvee/exifr/).

Have also added the appropriate migrations to the DB, which appear as should on the schema.

The view renders `undefined method`latitude'`

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you want imgfile.gps_latitude and imgfile.gps_longitude - underscored instead of dots